# ios12 dual sims cellular data carrier

Tags: ios12, dual-sim, carrier

How can i get the carrier of  cellular data sim card with dual sims of iphone XR or iphoneXS max. I got two cards carrier info, but can't find the  cellular data one.

```
CTCarrier *carrier;
if (@available(iOS 12.1, *)) {
    if ([self.telephonyNetworkInfo respondsToSelector:@selector(serviceSubscriberCellularProviders)]) {
        NSArray *carrierInfos = [[self.telephonyNetworkInfo performSelector:@selector(serviceSubscriberCellularProviders)] allValues];
        if (carrierInfos && [carrierInfos count] > 0) {
            carrier = carrierInfos[0];
        }
    }
} else if (@available(iOS 12.0, *)) {
    if ([self.telephonyNetworkInfo respondsToSelector:@selector(serviceSubscriberCellularProvider)]) {
        NSArray *carrierInfos = [[self.telephonyNetworkInfo performSelector:@selector(serviceSubscriberCellularProvider)] allValues];
        if (carrierInfos && [carrierInfos count] > 0) {
            carrier = carrierInfos[0];
        }
    }
}
if (!carrier) {
    carrier = [self.telephonyNetworkInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
}
```

debug infos:
[xcode console lldb info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOL2z.jpg)